# SQL/Sybase: SELECT ... GROUP BY ... NOT HAVING?

Tags: sql, group-by, sybase

```
col1   col2
A      bear
A      dog
A      cat
B      bear
B      dog
B      cat
C      dog
C      cat
D      bear
D      dog
D      cat
E      bear
E      dog
E      cat
F      dog
F      cat
```

if I wanted to select all of the col1 values that have at least one row where `col2 = 'bear'`, I can do:

```
SELECT col1 
FROM mytable 
WHERE col1 IN ('A','B','C') 
GROUP BY col1 
HAVING col2 = 'bear'
```

which would return A and B

but I want to select only the values from col1 where there isn't a row where `col2 = 'bear'`

I'm thinking `NOT HAVING`, but that doesn't appear to work.

any ideas? thanks!

Comment: Does `Having Col2 != 'bear'` get what you need?

Comment: that would return A,B, and C, though, because `col2 = 'cat'` and `'dog'` each satisfies `col2 != 'bear'`

Comment: No worries.  I don't spend as much time with SQL these days as I used to.  Where Not exists was my next suggestion, but it's already in an answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
SELECT m1.col1
     FROM mytable m1
     WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT NULL 
                          FROM mytable m2 
                          WHERE m2.col1 = m1.col1 
                              AND m2.col2 = 'bear')
         AND m1.col1 IN ('A', 'B', 'C')
```

Comment: awesome, thanks! I just edited it to make it a little closer to reality with lots of rows: I know I can add `WHERE col1 IN (A,B,C)` to both of your SELECT statements, but is there a more elegant way?

Comment: @carillonator: You'd only need to add that condition to the outer `SELECT`. I've edited my answer to reflect this change.

Answer (score 9):

You could also use this trick:

```
SELECT col1 
FROM mytable
WHERE col1 IN ('A','B','C') 
GROUP BY col1 
HAVING SUM(CASE col2 WHEN 'bear' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)=0
```

Comment: Thanks. that helped me a lot and it is easier as the above solution, when you already have other tables joined in the query.